# how to change indicator color in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

as shown in the picture  blow i have first tab colored with green

tab title is colored put underline is not

[image: tab title is colored put underline is not]

is it possible to color the line under the title with the same color `green` ?

```
child: TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  isScrollable: false,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: getIndicatorAndLabelColor(selectedIndex),
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                  indicatorWeight: 4,
                  indicatorColor: getIndicatorAndLabelColor(selectedIndex),
                 indicatorPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 10),
                  indicator: const ShapeDecoration(
                      shape: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: myAccentColor,
                              width: 3,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid))),
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(
                      text: 'APPROVED',
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'DENIED',
                    ),
                    Tab(
                      text: 'PENDING',
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Yeasin Sheikh  , finally i found the solution

```
        indicator: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 3,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indicatorColor` to set it green.

```dart
TabBar(
  indicatorColor: Colors.green, //this one , you can remove `getIndicatorAndLabelColor`
  indicatorWeight: 4,
  indicatorPadding:
      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, bottom: 10),
  tabs: <Widget>[
```

Comment: i made a function to return the color i need, however, i used the same way that you mentioned and it doesn't work for me. do you think there is something wrong

Comment: Are you using theme level some point? Also try to remove other decoration as me and let me know